# mysql cursor execution

Tags: mysql

ERROR -

---

Error

```
SQL query:

call cursorproc(
@p_out
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

---

AFTER EXECUTING - called stored procedure

```
call cursorproc (@p_out);
select @p_out as temp;
```

---

FOLLOWING CODE EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY - stored procedure

```
create procedure cursorproc(OUT p_out DECIMAL(10,2))
begin

   declare l_salary, l_total DECIMAL(10,2);

   declare cur_1 cursor for select line_distance from elements;
   
   open cur_1;

   set l_total = 0;

   loop

      fetch cur_1 into l_salary;

      
         set l_total = l_total + l_salary;
      
  end loop;

   close cur_1;

   set p_out = l_total;

end;
```

---

Any solution to this where exactly we are missing? Help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should check end of dataset while reading data.
Have a look at example here - [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html).

Also, I'd suggest you to avoid opening cursor -

```
SELECT SUM(line_distance) INTO @var FROM  elements;
SELECT @var;
```